# gulp command error : cannot find module 'through2'?

Tags: npm, gulp, npm-install

I installed the gulp to global and local project:

```
npm install -g gulp
```

and

```
npm install --save-dev gulp
```

then I use gulp command:

```
 gulp -v
```

then,display error:

```
module.js:471
throw err;
^
Error: Cannot find module 'through2'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/users/zhangzhida/output/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/gulp-util/lib/noop.js:1:77)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
```

Then ,I install the through2 to global and local project. still display error like 
the above. when I re-install the gulp after installed the through2 ,is also like the above.

I  think it is some problem in npm ,but I don't know how to resolve it .Please help me.

Comment: Can you delete your node_modules folder and rerun `npm install` again and check?

Comment: do `npm cache clean` and then delete `node_modules` and then `npm install`

Comment: Yes ,I tried .It's not work.

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not sure if it will help, here's how to use gulp.

## Update NodeJS and npm

If not done already, install the latest stable version of NodeJS and immediately run:

```
npm install -g npm
```

This will update npm with npm.

## Installing gulp

The first thing you see on their website is the npm commands to **install the gulp package to your local project, and the gulp CLI program globally** as a tool.

```
npm install gulp-cli -g
npm install gulp -D
```

Since so much people confuses the gulp package with the gulp CLI package, the doc says:

> If you've previously installed gulp globally, run `npm rm --global gulp`
>   before [installing the CLI again]

## Using gulp with a project

Gulp is a development dependency in your project, like any other package needed to build your project. So you shouldn't install `through2` globally, only locally in the project as a dev dependency.